# How to navigate in web app using user defined buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

In my web application, I want to provide two arrows, one for forward and another for backward navigation. Although the user can use the browser's navigation features but I want to implement it using jQuery by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the only way but as long as you're happy to use JavaScript then try something like;

```
<Form><input value="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"> </form>
```

..and as you requested a way without submitting a form;

```
<A HREF="javascript:history.go(-1)">
Go back
</A>

<A HREF="javascript:history.go(1)">
Go forward
</A>
```

In both examples above we are using JavaScript's "history object" to go back and forward.

Comment: Why the `form` and `input`? Why not just `a` tag?

Comment: As per your request I have edited above so there is also a method without the use of a form, does this suit your needs?

Comment: yah its perfect.!!! :)

Comment: Great news, happy to help!